# Rails 5.1 Secrets vi ended up with two files to edit

Tags: vim, ruby-on-rails-5, credentials

I'm using Rails 5.1.2

I'm having some difficulty with the secrets.yml files.

I have somehow ended up with two files that are holding my secrets. When I run `vi secrets:edit` I see an empty file.  Then when I close it using
`esc q` instead of it closing it will show me another file and will say `E173: 1 more file to edit` So I have to repeat `esc q` before I can get back to my bash profile.

Neither file show my Environment keys that I know are saved somewhere because the app is able to run and function when I run `Rails s` but I just can't access them.

How can I find the missing file and delete these empty files?

Comment: Well, `esc q` is not supposed to close the current buffer/window/tab page or even to quit Vim to begin with. `esc q` leaves the current mode and tells Vim to start a recording and then Vim waits for a register. From insert mode, you would do `<Esc>:wq<CR>` to write and quit or `<Esc>:q!<CR>` to quit without writing. As for why you get two files to edit, are you sure you are really typing `vi secrets:edit` and not something else? Anyway, use nano.

Comment: Hi yes you are right.  I just didn't know how to express `<Esc> :q!` correctly when I was typing my question, but what you have written is what I was using.  

I discovered what I needed to do was write the following
`EDITOR="vi" bin/rails secrets:edit` and then it would open up the correct file for me with all my environment variables there.  

Thanks for your input.